# How can CKA_TRUSTED be set to true?

Tags: pkcs11

I'm confused by the wording of the PKCS#11 v2.40 specification in terms of when `CKA_TRUSTED` can be set to true on a public key certificate object:

> The CKA_TRUSTED attribute cannot be set to CK_TRUE by an application. It MUST be set by a token 
>   initialization application or by the token’s SO. Trusted certificates cannot be modified.

I'm trying to reconcile *"cannot be set to CK_TRUE by an application"* and *"It MUST be set [...] by the token's SO"*.  Does this mean a R/W SO session can create (or update) a Public Key Certificate Object (e.g. `CKC_WTLS`) with `CKA_TRUSTED` set to `CK_TRUE`?  I feel this doesn't jive well with *"cannot be set [...] by an application"*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general an application - a program that uses the token for cryptographic operations - is supposed to use `CKU_USER`, not `CKU_SO`.

The `CKU_SO` is supposed to be used by the security officer. Of course, the only way that the SO can generally communicate with the token is through some kind of *management application* - sometimes combined with an authentication device such as an external PIN pad connected to an HSM. And yes, *usually* it is possible to write a management application yourself; it is of course dubious at best to mix that into an application that uses the key material stored within the token (especially if you also integrate the login credentials).

And yes, the SO can generally set trust on certificates. The SO is responsible for making sure that they can be trusted after all.

---

There can be tokens where the trust cannot be set at all. For instance smart cards may have a specific PKCS#11 interface where no management operations are applicable whatsoever.

Comment: Thank you.  I think my confusion was how PKCS#11 defines what an 'application' is.  I took it as anything using the `Cryptoki` API, which a _management application_ _may_ use but could use other interfaces accessible only to an authenticated `CKU_SO` user.  So I feel in general that:

1.) Support for the `CKA_TRUSTED` attribute is optional, but if it is supported then,

2.) It can be set but _only_ by a `CKU_SO` and not through the standard `Cryptoki` API application.

Comment: Being the SO is a question of authenticating as SO, so *if* the application authenticates as such then yes, it is a cryptoki application and yes, the application can then change the attribute. SO is part of the cryptoki API after all, and you'd use standard calls for it. It would however not be a *user* application, that fulfills a specific use case. Some HSM's have an admin user on top of an SO by the way, generally those use proprietary API's.